# Problem installing Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, network-bonding

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.10 but I am stuck on the network connection/create bond page.
Anyone that can help me with the settings?

Comment: You'll have to provide us more detail for us to help you, which part of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding are you stuck at for example?  and did you follow the links to further more detailed information?

Comment: During installation appears a page (the 4th of 11) called network connection. It says I have to create a bond, I have tried different settings for the bond but it says it's only 50 or 75% done and I can't continue.

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop  Are you talking about Ubuntu 18.10 (Desktop) or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is Ubuntu 18.10 but the look of installation pages is nothing like what's shown in tutorials, it's a lot more minimalistic

Comment: Which is why I asked which 18.10 you had downloaded and were using. If you include official flavors & different architectures, there are far more than 20 options that install Ubuntu 18.10, and way more than that unofficial variants (eg. modified and tweaked by cloud producers).  The most used being being the Ubuntu 18.10 Desktop (x86_64) that the tutorial was written for.  If you are using another official ISO we need you to tell us (as what you see is different), if using an unofficial (not included in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors) then you may not have an official product.

Comment: It was downloaded from the official site and it's called ubuntu-18.10-live-server-amd64.

Comment: Why didn't you say it was the server edition earlier?   https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server is the equivalent tutorial to my prior link for server installs (but ~75% want the desktop edition).  With IT (technology) you need to be specific to get useful advice that's close to your needs.  A quick glance makes it looks like this guide is not geared at 'live' installer, so https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-live-server.html.en maybe more useful to you.

Comment: Thank you, finally I have found the guide I was looking for!

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-from-cd.html.it